# how to concatenate a variable in group and name in adress, on vim autocmd?

Tags: vim

I'm trying make a auto header fuction on vim, to gerate auto header for any file type c, php, python and etc, and I only make the template in folder  ~/.vim, but I want get the type in a variable and send to group and adress of autocmd BufNewFile.

Something like that:

```
let type=expand('%:e')
au BufNewFile *. .type  so '~/.vim/.type._header.txt'
```

But the vim not see type like a variable, see that a string, somebody have an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vim's evaluation rules are different than most programming languages. You need to use `:execute` in order to evaluate a variable (or expression); otherwise, it's taken literally; i.e. Vim uses the variable name itself as the argument.

```
let type = expand('%:e')
execute 'au BufNewFile *.'  . type  'so ~/.vim/' . type . '_header.txt'
```

I would probably use `printf()` instead of concatenation to improve readability.

```
execute printf('au BufNewFile *.%s so ~/.vim/%s_header.txt', type, type)
```

---

Note that with your approach, you're basically duplicating the built-in *filetype detection*, which already provides a mapping of file extensions to types. I would rather define a generic hook into `BufNewFile`, and then evaluate `&filetype`. You just need to make sure that your event is defined *after* the one for filetype detection, e.g. by moving the definition from `~/.vimrc` into a `~/.vim/plugin/` script.

Comment: The printf way is more readable IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say you'd better use one of the template expander plugins. There are plenty, they already do the job, and much more.

Regarding the how, in [mu-template](https://github.com/LucHermitte/mu-template), I have a `au BufNewFile` that triggers a function call where I simply use `&ft` (instead of `expand('%:e')`) to pick the right template-file.

Regarding string manipulations, Ingo has already pointed out that you've forgotten to extract the variable name from the string. i.e. it should have been:

```
au BufNewFile * exe '0read ~/.vim/'.&ft.'_header.txt'
```